# Программа про факториал

Tags: pascal

Нужно написать программу, которая определяет частоту появления в числе x! цифры y (x<=100).
Факториал я считаю.

```
function fact(n : integer) : longint;
  begin
    if n <= 1 then
      fact := 1
    else
      fact := n * fact(n - 1);
  end;
```

Comment: Числа y или цифры y?

Comment: @GanjaBoss используйте комментарии к вопросу.

Comment: Цифры. В ТЗ так написано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для умножения тупо использовал два массива цифр. Вывод полученного факториала закоменнтарен

```
program digifact;
const ndig=1000;
var n, i, dig, highest, j:integer;
    prod, prod1: array [1..ndig] of integer;
begin
    write('Введите n>');
    readln(n);
    write('Введите цифру>');
    readln(dig);
    for i:=1 to ndig do 
    begin
        prod[i] := 0;
        prod1[i] := 0
    end;
    highest:=1;
    prod[highest] := 1;
    for i := 2 to n do
    begin
        for j:=1 to highest do prod1[j] := prod[j] * i;
        for j:=1 to highest do
        begin
            prod[j] := prod1[j] mod 10;
            prod1[j+1] := prod1[j+1] + prod1[j] div 10
        end;
        j := highest+1;
        while prod1[j] > 0 do
        begin
            highest := j;
            prod[j] := prod1[j] mod 10;
            prod1[j+1] := prod1[j] div 10;
            inc(j)
        end
    end;
    (* for i:=highest downto 1 do write(prod[i]);
    writeln; *)
    j := 0;
    for i:=1 to highest do
        if prod[i] = dig then inc(j);
    writeln('В числе ', n, '! ', j, ' цифр ', dig);
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

13! = 6227020800 > 2147483647 = `maxlongint`.

Чтобы посчитать факториал в явном виде, нужно использовать длинную арифметику.

PS Мне кажется, что без явного вычисления факториала тут не обойтись.